# Need help understand the behavior of URLs for a django website

Tags: python, django

I am coding a website for practice which has the following functionality
1) Display employee data (localhost:8000/payroll)
2) Add Employee (localhost:8000/addemployee)
3) Edit Employee (localhost:8000/editemployee)
4) Download report (localhost:8000/downloadreport)

Below screenshots indicate the operations as they happen.

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRYue.png)

[delete employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfBam.png)

Code for my deleteemployee view is as follows where if the delete succeeds I use render to take the user back to my home page(at least I think that is how it should work). But if you notice the URL never changes to index i.e localhost:8000/payroll even though the homepage is displayed the delete employee URL is still showing. What am I doing wrong here ?

**EXPECTED URL AFTER CLICKING REMOVE IS BELOW**
http://127.0.0.1:8000/payroll/

**ACTUAL URL AFTER CLICKING REMOVE IS BELOW**
http://127.0.0.1:8000/payroll/deleteemployee?employee_id=32

Python Version -- 3.7
Django Version -- 3.0

````
 try:
    e = Employee.objects.get(employee_id = request.GET.get('employee_id'))
    e.delete()
    employee_list = Payroll.objects.select_related('employee_id')                  
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'employee_list' : employee_list })
 except Exception:
    return render(request, 'error.html',{'error':'Delete Operation Failed'})```
````

Comment: If you want to change the URL in the clients browser you'll need to use a redirect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Many thanks !!! Based on reading the doc I knew render wasn't correct. Now changed to redirect('/payroll') and it's working just fine.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, please accept it. Also note the use of `reverse` to generate the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)ing a response, you'll need to return a [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to change the URL in the client browser. E.g.,

```
return redirect("/payroll")
```

Note, however, you should use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) to generate the URL rather than hard-coding it. E.g.,

```
return redirect(reverse("myapp:payroll"))
```